# Is silverlight can be use in wpf windows application?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

Is silverlight can be use in wpf windows application?

Some slight confusion about it, what benefits of silverlight may be taken in wpf windows application?

Is there any licensing required for silverlight developement and deployment?

Comment: why you want to do that? are you trying to ask that can you host external silverligh application from internet domain inside your own wpf application? using Browser control etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Silverlight can be developed with [WebDeveloper Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) (with [the addon](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9442B0F2-7465-417A-88F3-5E7B5409E9DD&displaylang=en)), IIRC - so no you don't have any inbuilt license costs - but it would be easier with Blend and VS Pro or above. Of course, WPF can be developed with [C# Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/), so also free!

But fundamentally they are different products; Silverlight is a slimmer version designed for cross-platform use with RIA - originally in the browser, but now out-of-browser too with Silverlight 3. WPF is windows / .NET 3.0 specific, but has a richer framework.

Comment: Applications written for one can be ported to the other with some effort.

Comment: Exactly, written properly with Prism (or perhaps caliburn) the amount of shared codebase can be really large.